# Homotopy category of $\text{mod}\,A$ Krull-Schmidt for $\text{gl dim}\,A = \infty$?

Tags: representation-theory, homological-algebra, triangulated-categories

I'm interested in the Grothendieck group of the triangulated category $K^b(\text{proj} A)$ in the following setting:

- $A$ is a finite dimensional algebra with $\text{gl dim} A = \infty$.
- $K^b(\text{proj} A)$ is the bounded homotopy category and $\text{proj} A$ is the additive category of finite dimensional projective modules.

It would be helpful to know if in this case $K^b(\text{proj} A)$ is Krull-Schmidt, but I couldn't find much about it.

What is so far known about the Krull-Schmidt property of $K^b(\text{proj} A)$ or its Grothendieck group?

I would appreciate any literature reference!

Thanks:)